# How to get variable defined inside of jQuery custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a custom jQuery plugin. I need to access the options passed in the first function within the second function.

The problem is if I declare settings outside of these functions, it gets mixed up when I have multiple instances of this plugin initialized on the same page.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.MyCombobox = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            selector: '.myselector'
        }, options);
    };

    $.fn.MyCombobox.clear = function() {
        $(settings.selector).find('input').val('');
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: How are the methods used?

Comment: Maybe try assigning the variable `settings` to something? Right now it's just a var in a function with no way to get a reference to it outside that function.

Comment: i would use the clear function in whatever page i am using the plugin. So I would initialize the plugin like: `$('#mydiv').MyCombobox({selector: '.myinput'});` and then I could add an event listener to say clear the inputs when I click a button and that should be used like this: `$('#mydiv').MyCombobox.clear()` There is a lot more the plugin and its not just doing that but I wanted to simplify it to ask on here.

Comment: @gforce301 So I originally have `var settings;` Outside both those functions but when I initialize it more than once on a single page, they both use the same settings variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to set `.data()` at `.MyCombobox`

```js
(function($) {

    $.fn.MyCombobox = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            selector: '.myselector'
        }, options);
        this.data("options", settings);
        return this
    };

    $.fn.clear = function() {
      console.log(this.data("options") || {/* default settings here */})
    };

}(jQuery));

$("div").MyCombobox().clear();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```